# How to globally detect device active orientation changes outside of a swift-file?

Tags: swift, orientation, rounded-corners, cornerradius

I am having trouble in figuring out how to update the corner radii in the calculator view controller (see the images in the link at the end of this post). I am setting the corner radius using viewWillLayoutSubviews() and so far it has been working great. However, I noticed that if I transition away from the calculator view controller screen, rotate the device, and navigate back to the calculator view controller screen, the corner radius is still based on the previous orientation screen. I have tried recalling viewWillLayoutSubviews() inside viewDidAppear(), But there is a noticeable delay before the buttons corner radii gets set correctly.

How can I tell if the device orientation changed while being in the library or some other view controller? I need to be able to load circular buttons when navigating back to the calculator screen. Thank you for your time I appreciate any input you all may be able to provide me. Thank you for your time!

[Screenshots of my current application from loading screen to the point of the corner radius not being updated correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4auL6.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

you can do like that in your viewdidLoad add below code for check device orientation

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
 object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

now everytime that check device orientation when coming and according to that in below code reload your view

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your app delegate. So you know if the device is in landscape or portrait mode globally. You can then use Viewwill appear to change the radius.

```
import UIKit


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

var didRotate: (Notification) -> Void = { notification in
    switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
    case .landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight:
        print("landscape")
    case .portrait, .portraitUpsideDown:
        print("Portrait")
    default:
        print("other")
    }
}



func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification,
                                           object: nil,
                                           queue: .main,
                                           using: didRotate)


    return true
}

}
```

Comment: I get the following error: "Use of undeclared type 'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate'"

Comment: Taking a look now at it! Thank you!

Comment: Ok. Have tested it on the device to check if it works. Please mark correct if it worked for you.